# Refresh contents of dialog

Tags: android

I need to update a custom dialog content whenever that dialog is ready to be drawin. I am not sure this could be refreshed directly or if I need to close it first and re-instatiate it?

Comment: Do you want to update some value of a view in the dialog or completely redraw it using a new layout of views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the view that the Dialog is using and [post]invalidate it.

Instead of `Dialog.setContentView(int)`;

Do something like:

```
public class MyDialog {
        View v = null;

        public Dialog show(Context context) {
            Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.resource, null);
            d.setContentView(v);
            return d.show();
        }

        public void update() {
            v.invalidate();
        }
}
```

Comment: I can't see under which circumstances such redrawing will be needed. Could you, possibly, clarify it for me?

Comment: If one wanted a Service to update a Dialog [ProgressBar maybe?], is one.

Comment: @AshishDwivedi What is your solution?

Comment: ok, but LayoutInflater is taking only one argument as Context.

Answer (score -3):

You can do everything in `onPrepareDialog`. It is called every time a dialog is about to be shown.

```
void onPrepareDialog(final int id, final Dialog dialog) {
     switch(id) {
     case MY_DIALOG:
        TextView txtView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        txtView.setText("My new text"):
        ....
     }
}
```

Comment: OP wanted to update the dialog `After` is has been created and shown.