# How to update dialogue in android

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, window

I have a popup dialog where the user inputs data, including a date. To select the date, I have a button to open another window with a date picker. When I select the date and it returns to the first dialog, the text field with the date is not changed unless I open the date picker a second time. How would I refresh or update the first dialog immediately after I return to it from the date picker window?

Here is the code for the first dialog:

```
public void addEntry(View view) {
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    d.setTitle("Add Entry");
    d.setCancelable(true);      
    d.show();

    ...

    chooseDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str = selectDate();
            date.setText(str);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Here is the code for the second window where you would choose the date:

```
public String selectDate(){

    final Dialog datePicker = new Dialog(this);
    datePicker.setContentView(R.layout.choose_date);
    datePicker.setTitle("Choose Date...");
    datePicker.setCancelable(true);
    datePicker.show();

    Button selectFinalDate = (Button) datePicker.findViewById(R.id.selectDate);
    final DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) datePicker.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

    selectFinalDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            strDateTime = (dp.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dp.getDayOfMonth() + "/" + dp.getYear();
            datePicker.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return strDateTime;
};
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Put date.setText(datechoosen) in the second dialog on click and it will set the textView or button or whatever view that shows the date on the first dialog. Make it static in case it is not accessible in the second dialog but check if it is not null before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but should work.

```
...
 date.setText(str);
 view.invalidate(); // the view that you are showing in the dialog
...
```

so in your code, you update this :

```
/**
* global variable for your dialog view
*/
View view =null;

                // in your addEntry(View view)
                ...
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                view  = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                d.setContentView(view);
                ...

                 // selectDate()
                 ...
                 date.setText(str);
                 view.invalidate(); // the view that you are showing in the dialog
                 ...
```

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233242/refresh-contents-of-dialog)