# How to refresh the contents of AlertDialog immediately

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, disabled-control

Here's my problem. I have a button which is disabled if there's no date that you currently choose. My problem is every time I choose the date, my condition in my program doesn't work. The button should be immediately enabled if I chose my desired date. But the button still disabled after I currently put my desired date. It will only work when I press the outside of the window of AlertDialog, and press again the button that will load the Alert dialog, the button will update and the button is enabled.

[image: AlertDialog with disabled button],

[image: AlertDialog when I choose my desired date],

[image: AlertDialog when I press the button that will show the AlertDialog]

**Here's the portion of my program:**

```
private void Button(final String bookTitle, final String id) {
    mBorrowed = "not borrowed";

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.borrow_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout));

    dialogBuilder.setView(view);


    tvScheduleDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleDate);
    tvReturnDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReturnDate);
    tvSchedule = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSchedule);
    btnRequest = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnRequest);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    tvSchedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Borrow.this, Borrow.this, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); //for max date
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();


        }
    });

    btnRequest.setEnabled(false);
    if (dayFinal > 0) {
        btnRequest.setEnabled(true);

        btnRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            /*

            String format_date = yearFinal + "-" + monthFinal  + "-" + dayFinal ;
            String ids = databaseBorrow.push().getKey();
            String buttonText = btnBorrow.getText().toString();
            BorrowBook borrow = new BorrowBook(ids,buttonText,bookTitle,getPresentDate(format_date),getFutureDate(format_date));
            databaseBorrow.child(ids).setValue(borrow);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Borrow Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                btnRequest.setEnabled(false);
                if (mBorrowed.equals("not borrowed")) {
                    databaseBorrow.child("Borrow").child(user.getUid()).child(id).child("request_type").setValue("sent").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                databaseBorrow.child("Borrow").child(id).child(user.getUid()).child("request_type").setValue("received").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        btnRequest.setEnabled(true);
                                        mBorrowed = "req_sent";
                                        btnRequest.setText("Cancel Borrowed Request");
                                        //Toast.makeText(Borrow.this,"Request Sent Successfully"+mBorrowed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Borrow.this, "Failed request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (mBorrowed.equals("req_sent")) {
                    databaseBorrow.child("Borrow").child(user.getUid()).child(id).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            databaseBorrow.child("Borrow").child(id).child(user.getUid()).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    btnRequest.setEnabled(true);
                                    mBorrowed = "not borrowed";
                                    btnRequest.setText("Send Borrowed Request");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: see this solution it could be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233242/refresh-contents-of-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233242/refresh-contents-of-dialog)

Comment: I already saw this thread and it doesn't show any solution that I want.

Comment: if you are talking about `btnRequest` of course it will stay disabled because you don't have a callback method or event to enabled the button. `if` statement is never triggered. Try by implementing `OnDateSetListener` on `DatePickerDialog` and enable the button inside when user sets the date.

Comment: @Excalibur please have to look my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Positive** and **Negative** on `DatePickerDialog`

**Like this:**

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Borrow.this, Borrow.this, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); //for max date
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                btnRequest.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                btnRequest.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
            datePickerDialog.show();
```

**OR**

You can use **DatePicker** instead of using **DatapickerDialogue**

**Like this:**

```
final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(mActivity);
        datePicker.setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("Picker", datePicker.getDayOfMonth() + " : " + datePicker.getMonth() + " : " + datePicker.getYear());

                        btnRequest.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                btnRequest.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                        }).setView(datePicker).show();
```